# Chm file displaying Page can not be displayed

Tags: chm

I have created compiled html (chm) file using the Microsoft html Help Workshop. when I tried to open the generated chm file, it is showing message "Page Can not be displayed". But when I click on content topic only then I am able to see corresponding page content.

Do I need to set any thing so show the selected page by default.

Answer (score 3):

The short way:
If the CHM help file resides on a network drive please copy this file to a local hard drive first and try again. You'll find some additional and troubleshooting information at:

http://www.help-info.de/en/xml/maml_troubleshooting_hh.xml

http://www.grainge.org/pages/authoring/chm_mspatch/896358.htm

**Problem:** The help file will appear, but instead of the topic text you will see an error message "this page cannot be displayed".

**Cause:** Microsoft released some security patches that makes it impossible to view CHM files that are stored on a network drive (as opposed to CHM files stored on your own computer).

**Solution:** There is a work-around to allow viewing across a network as discussed on the following links:

http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2928.aspx

http://www.helpscribble.com/chmnetwork.html

The problems can also occur if the CHM file name or the path to the file contains a number sign (#). If the CHM file name contains the # symbol, then the topics in the table of contents do not appear. If the path contains the # symbol, then you may receive an access violation error message. 
To work around this issue, remove the # symbol from the file name or from the path to the file.

If you have a compiled collection of CHM's (so called "merged CHM") some other problems are possible.

---

If you are new in using HTMLHelp Workshop:

**Question:** Is there a way to set a default page to be displayed when a .chm file is opened? I would like to display the page associated with the first item in the Table of Contents.

**Answer:** You can do this with Microsoft HTMLHelp Workshop.

1. Open your HHP file with HH Workshop
2. Click the first icon "Change project options" on the "Project" tab
3. Set the "Default file" from the file list of the combo box
4. Compile your project

HHP file example (open with notepad):

```
\\\
..
[OPTIONS]
Binary TOC=No
Binary Index=Yes
Compiled File=Help_Coding-Example_VB6.chm
Contents File=Help_Coding-Example_VB6.hhc
Index File=Help_Coding-Example_VB6.hhk
Default Window=main
Default Topic=index.htm
..
///
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution:

1. In your HTML Help Workshop go to the "Project" tab
2. Press button "Change project options"
3. In the "Default file" field put the name of your default file which is already exist in your project. File should have .htm extension  (for example about.htm)
4. Compile project again and you will see that problem is fixed